# Can I use AD to control who can install software based on their role?

Tags: active-directory, installation, software

A scenario.
You have to group of employees, identified in AD as Agents and Engineers.
Can I set up controls so that:
Agents cannot install software
Engineers CAN install software

Thank you in Advance
Jame

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppLocker policies to allow users to run, or prevent users from running, typical Windows Installer files, based on group membership. However, catching .exe files takes a significant amount of planning and auditing, and long-term maintenance as you will need to set AppLocker to only allow selected .exe files to run.

You can prevent users from installing software on a system-wide level by not granting administrative rights on the client computer. The proper way to grant some users the ability to make administrative changes on client computers is to create a dedicated administrative account for them, and then control access via that account. Granting regular user accounts administrative rights is a security risk, and should be avoided; likewise you should not be granting these accounts Domain Admin rights, just because it's easiest.

The easiest way to accomplish that is by creating a group for the Engineer's administrative accounts, then create a GPO to add the Admin Engineers group to the local Administrators group on the client computers.